# How to persiste the state of a ListFragment when CAB is activated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-screen-support

I'm trying to create an activity that manipulate two fragments one is a ListFragment and the other is a WebViewFragment and I have two different layouts xml, one .xml under res/layout folder (single pane layout that host a FrameLayout) and the other under res/layout-w720dp folder (two pane layout that contains the two fragments).

I'm having trouble persisting the state of the activity in general at orientation change (specially when Contextual Action Bar is activate and some item are selected in the ListFragment)

how to passe the state of one ListFragment to another ?

Comment: Do you have enabled `.setRetainInstanceState(true)`?

Comment: Yes I try it, but cause an exception: `02-21 12:33:13.462: E/AndroidRuntime(26515): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment SessionsFragment{428fa938 #0 id=0x7f080037}: was 2131230775 now 2131230774`

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I think in this case set `.setRetainInstanceState(true)` won't work because there is two different layout where one fragment is created via xml and the other programmatically added to the container FrameLayout. so I end up with two different fragments that has different states